# Variance of Influence Functions, Cross-fitting, and the Propensity Score

Tags: machine-learning, variance, causality, propensity-scores, influence-function

Following example 2 in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.06469), suppose I wanted to estimate $\psi = E[E[Y|X,A=a]] $ and I had an influence function follows:
$$
IF(\psi) = \frac{A}{\pi(X)}\{Y-\mu(X)\} - \psi
$$
where $\pi(X)$ is the propensity score and $\mu(X) = E[Y|X,A=a]$. With estimator
$$
\hat{\psi} = \mathbb{P}_n\bigg[\hat{\mu}(X) + \frac{A\{Y-\hat{\mu}(X)\}}{\hat{\pi}(X)}\bigg]
$$

To estimate this I could do cross-fitting/sample-splitting to get $\hat{\mu}$ and $\hat{\pi}$: train a model on one-half the data and simply plug in the predicted values on the other half. It is unclear to me whether this estimator's variance considers the fact that there is downstream variability in fitting the models for the $\mu$ and $\pi$ on the separate partition of data. We may not have to due to cross-fitting but I am not sure. In essence, the question is can we treat $\hat{\mu}$ and $\hat{\pi}$ as fixed due cross-fitting?

Comment: This is a good question and one of the miracles of doubly-robust inference. Unfortunately I don't have the technical knowledge to explain it any further. But I believe the IF arises from the nature of the estimator, not the cross-fitting. Cross-fitting allows the estimator to be consistent for a broader class of data-generating models than otherwise.

Comment: The following chapter might be helpful. Particularly, section 2.7.2 https://statnav.files.wordpress.com/2017/10/doublerobustness-preprint.pdf

Comment: @Noah I guess the question surrounds the variance of the IF with and without cross-fitting. If we didn't use cross-fitting, we definitely have to account for the simultaneous estimation of the propensity score, etc. But perhaps cross-fitting allows us to instead treat these as fixed, making the variance derivation much easier.

Comment: @RoyZ I don't think this is so. As described in the article linked above, as long as the estimators of the nuisance functionals converge each at rate faster than $n^{1/4}$, the IF for the estimator is the same as the IF for an estimator where the functionals were known. As I said, this really is the "miracle" of doubly-robust inference, because we don't need to incorporate the variability of the nuisance functionals to perform valid inference on the quantity of interest. But we do need to know the converge rate of the functionals and they need to achieve a certain rate.

Comment: @Noah what you're saying is correct but let me also present this piece of evidence. [In this paper](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00031305.2020.1717620), in the paragraph under Eq. (3.8) they state: "Studying these estimates is fairly straightforward if $\tilde{P}$ can be treated as fixed, for instance, if $\tilde{P}$ is estimated a priori or using sample splitting." I wonder how the two pieces from the paper given by pzivich and this link together.

Comment: I don't have the bandwidth to make a rigorous explanation at the moment, but cross-fitting is *exactly* what allows you to treat $\hat{\mu}$, $\hat{\pi}$ as fixed (bc they're fit on the "other" fold(s)), and make statements about asymptotic variance. See Stefan [Wager's notes (Lecture 3) on DR estimators](https://web.stanford.edu/~swager/stats361.pdf).

Comment: Here's [a different estimator where cross-fitting is similarly used](https://csc2541-2022.github.io/lectures/CSC2541_lecture7_dml.pdf) in the variance derivation. The latter also demonstrates that, for worse-than $\sqrt{n}$-consistent estimators, no cross-fitting may cause asymptotic variance to diverge.